# Can you use "of yours" for a noun that has a superlative adjective?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

I have a question about the usage of the pronoun "those" with the pronoun "of yours" like in this sentence:

> The only one who knows "those" worst secrets of yours is me.

I know that if I used only "those secrets of yours" it would be correct. But with the superlative adjective "worst", is it still correct, acceptable, or even beautiful to speak that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site. Adding the superlative does not really change the underlying grammar of the sentence. Even with the superlative, the sentence is still correct and acceptable. Whether it is "beautiful" or not is a matter of taste, and beyond the scope of this site.